# What is the idiomatic way to propagate error from value inside map statement in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a function which returns a `Result<u32, SomeError>`. I want to collect four values from this function, and collect them to sum them up. How can you propagate the error inside the map operator? I want to stop on the first error, and propagate the error up to the function which called it

Works

```
(0..4)
    .map(|_| self.consume().unwrap())
    .collect::<Vec<u32>>()
    .iter()
    .sum::<u32>();
```

Does not work

```
(0..4)
    .map(|_| self.consume()?)
    .collect::<Vec<u32>>()
    .iter()
    .sum::<u32>();
```

The compiler error is

```
.map(|_| self.consume()?)
     ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------------
     |   |
     |   cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `u32`
     this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
```

Comment: When you encounter an error, what do you want to do? Skip it? Collect into vec of `Result`s? Stop on the first error? Collect into a `Result<Vec>` and fail completely if there was an error?

Answer (score 3):

`map()` is just an iterator adapater. It cannot propagate the error itself, since it doesn't run the code that can produce it. The executor of the code here is `sum()` (actually, `collect()`, but it is redundant here) and thus it should deal with the error (or a replacement).

In this case, you can exploit the fact that [`Result` implements `Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/iter/traits/accum.rs.html#145-172), allowing you to sum into `Result<T, E>`:

```rust
(0..4).map(|_| self.consume()).sum::<Result<u32, _>>()?;
```

`collect()` also does the same, so you can collect into `Result<Vec<T>, E>` for example.

Comment: For both myself and the OP, does this occur as you go, or are all of the `map` calls done before the `sum` is attempted?  That was one of the OP's requirements, that it stops on the first error.

Comment: @KevinAnderson As I said, `map()` does nothing but produces an iterator. It is lazy (otherwise, it would have to keep the results in a `Vec`). The real work is done in `sum()`, and it processes the element until the first error, by that time it discards the result and returns the error.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you very much! Is it possible to do something similar also if `consume` returns Result<char, _>, and then apply `.to_digit(x) (.unwrap()` on each of these chars? (this `self.consume().unwrap().to_digit(16).unwrap()`)

Comment: @jevoso5871 If they return the same error type, it's as easy as `self.consume()?.to_digit()`. If not, you may need to be more explicit and maybe specify the error type. But nonetheless, inside the closure you can use the normal `?` operator and all error handling facilities - you just need to return `Result` from it.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a [`Sum` instance for `Result<T, E>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html#impl-Sum%3CResult%3CU,%20E%3E%3E) that fits this usecase perfectly:

```rust
(0..4)
    .map(|_| self.consume())
    .sum::<Result<u32, _>>()?;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
(0..4)
    .map(|_| self.consume())
    .collect::<Result<Vec<u32>, _>>()?
    .iter()
    .sum::<u32>();
```